# Azure Fabric Service deployment regarding VM Size

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

My question is about deploying a Service Fabric.

I want to run a console app in Service Fabric. So I tried to deploy to Service Fabric, I followed the tutorial from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-creation-via-portal. But after deployment the Service Fabric status is stuck on Baseline Upgrades. (Not sure what this means but it is stuck for a day now). And the node nor my application is showing anymore. It was showing just the Application for a brief moment. I have read a thread on the internet where someone was saying that my virtual machine size could be to low for Azure Service Fabric to run. That I needed at least 14 GB of space. Can anyone confirm this?

I did change the virtual machine size to B1MS Standard instead of the recommended one D1_V2 Standard. Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried it with the recommended virtual machine size D1_V2 Standard. It is working fine now. My nodes are up and my application is running. So I guess the virtual machine size was just to small for Fabric Services.